# Query IN ORACLE to Optimize

Tags: sql, oracle, query-optimization

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT A_WEBC_URL AS FILE_LOCATION
    FROM BATELCO_BILLS_S
    WHERE BTL_BILL_I_NUMBER = :B2 AND BTL_BILL_I_ACC_NUMBER = '0' || :B1 
    UNION
    SELECT A_WEBC_URL AS FILE_LOCATION
    FROM BATELCO_BILLS_S
    WHERE BTL_BILL_I_NUMBER = :B2 AND (BTL_BILL_I_PROFILE_ID = :B1 OR
                                       BTL_BILL_I_PHONE_NUMBER = :B3 ) 
    UNION
    SELECT A_WEBC_URL AS SS
    FROM BATELCO_BILLS_S BILLS
    WHERE BILLS.BTL_BILL_I_PROFILE_ID = :B1 OR
        BTL_BILL_I_ACC_NUMBER = '0' || :B1 AND
        BILLS.BTL_BILL_I_NUMBER = :B2
)
WHERE ROWNUM = 1
```

The above query taking time to consume.Please help to optimize the code so that we can fetch the results easily.

Comment: This is another query please help

Comment: I don't see the point of the unions, which all select the same column from the same table.  Why do you think you need them?

Comment: Can't you replace the UNIONs with simple OR logic? If not can you use UNION ALL instead to remove the sort but permit duplicates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see the point of the unions, and I think we can rewrite the subquery without unions:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT A_WEBC_URL AS FILE_LOCATION
    FROM BATELCO_BILLS_S
    WHERE BTL_BILL_I_NUMBER = :B2 AND
         (BTL_BILL_I_ACC_NUMBER = '0' || :B1 OR
          BTL_BILL_I_PROFILE_ID = :B1 OR
          BTL_BILL_I_PHONE_NUMBER = :B3)
)
WHERE ROWNUM = 1
```

Note: I think the third query in your original union is missing parentheses around the first two terms in the `WHERE` clause.  That is, I think you intended the following logic:

```
...
UNION
SELECT A_WEBC_URL AS SS
FROM BATELCO_BILLS_S BILLS
WHERE (BILLS.BTL_BILL_I_PROFILE_ID = :B1 OR
    BTL_BILL_I_ACC_NUMBER = '0' || :B1) AND
    BILLS.BTL_BILL_I_NUMBER = :B2
```

Comment: Although it has no impact on performance, the subquery is not needed.

Answer (score 1):

This query should run very fast, 3 unions are not needed but they shouldn't affect performance much. And you don't have any nested loops or joined tables in your query.

If you have performance problems, I think you just need indexes on this table.
All of your WHERE conditions require checking of BTL_BILL_I_NUMBER field, so this query will run fast only if this column is indexed.

Do you have this column indexed?

If not, then you (or your DBA) should run:

```
CREATE INDEX IND_BTL_BILL_I_NUMBER ON BATELCO_BILLS_S (BTL_BILL_I_NUMBER);
```

If you don't see immediate effect, you (or your DBA) should gather Oracle optimizer stats for this table.